# Pandas pd.series returns a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to ask a question about Panda's series.

I am reading a book on Python on Data Science by O'Reilly publications and was reading on Pandas.

Consider the following code:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3), columns=list('bde'),
                index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
```

This code provides the following result.

```
        b        d         e
Utah    -0.81    0.43      -0.50
Ohio    1.67     -0.67     1.30
Texas   0.53     -0.32     0.80
Oregon  0.25     0.91      0.70
```

All values were manually expressed to 3 d.p. for convenience on SO.

Now, I learnt that functions can also return Series with multiple values:

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series([x.min(), x.max()], index=['min', 'max'])
```

as the literature states:

> Many of the most common array statistics (like sum and mean) are DataFrame methods, so using apply is not necessary. The function passed to apply need not return a scalar value; it can also return a Series with multiple values.

and running the following code

```
frame.apply(f)
```

produces the following result:

```
        b        d        e
min     -0.82    -0.67    -0.50
max     1.67     0.91     1.30
```

This code works.

However, I'm confused here.

I thought that a series should only be one dimensional i.e. pseudo-one-column data structures only with only indexes for each corresponding element.

e.g.

```
 >>> s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

 >>> s

a    0.469112
b   -0.282863
c   -1.509059
d   -1.135632
e    1.212112
dtype: float64
```

However, the result of the function appears to be a series of a two-dimensional nature, which doesn't make sense to me.

How has the function appeared to make a series of a two-dimensional nature?

Interestingly, doing

```
type(frame.applymap(format))
```

returns

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

which I don't know why it does.

Comment: You just confused with the result. Actually, the function only working on finding max and min then you apply it to your data frame.   frame.apply(f) hereafter returning the result to just apply it on your data frame so still related to the data frame on Series.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. @Amin the function returns a series, but we're still applying the function to each column i.e. `axis=0` so our end result after `frame.apply(f)` is a data frame EVEN though our initial function returns a `series` in the first place?

Comment: Yes exactly. By calling that function (' f ') we just try to show our method to the data frame then apply it to the data frame. The Data frame takes this function functionality and applies it to all columns.

Answer (score 0):

A Pandas Series is a 1D array of some type.  A DataFrame is a 2D array where each column is a Series and they can have different types.

However, the part you are probably missing is that the "type" can be the generic Python `object` which is a reference to any object.  For example:

```
pd.Series([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Gives you:

```
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

That is a 1D array of Python lists (which do not even have to have uniform length).

Using `object` dtype in Pandas (or NumPy) is usually suboptimal and should be avoided where possible.  In the above example you can just replace `Series` with `DataFrame` for a more optimal representation.  The `object` dtype is suboptimal because Pandas does not natively understand most of it, so any operations have to be done using the Python interpreter on each value in the array, rather than accelerated by compiled code as would be the case if the dtype were `int` or some other type Pandas natively understands.